# Should data-target="#my-modal" put inside a modal div in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, dismiss

I know that putting `data-target="#my-modal"` in the launch button outside the modal div is necessary. But should I also put that code in the dismiss button inside modal div? Or the machine always knows it's to dismiss the modal div where it's exactly in?

```
<button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#my-modal">Launch Modal</button>

    <div class="modal" id="my-modal"> <!-- this is modal div -->
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button> <!-- put `data-target="#my-modal"` in? -->
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Hello User!</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Welcome our dear user of our website!
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Dismiss</button> <!-- put `data-target="#my-modal"` in? -->
                    <button class="btn btn-success">Save Changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Additonal Info: This is how it looks.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply having `data-dismiss="modal"` such as the following will suffice:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
```

**However**, using multiple modals is **NOT** supported as cited [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).  You will need to write custom javascript if you would like to have multiple modals open at once.

Comment: Thanks! I've never thought of the multiple situation.